# Wordpress and Google Cloud Launcher issue with Contact Form

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

I've just installed the brand new Wordpress Beta for Google Cloud Launcher. Currently, I'm unable to send mail via Contact Form 7 and invites for things like new users via Wordpress admin. The funny thing is that I'm not getting any errors in console and the Contact 7 form doesn't show any failure.

Will I have to go the SMTP route with this? Is there anyone else who has had this issue with the new GCP Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a plugin for Wordpress that uses SMTP called Easy WP SMTP https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/.

I configured it to use smtp.google.com and a dummy account I made for the purpose of sending mail from Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Google Cloud documentation, Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25, 465, and 587. They suggest third party services to handle email, but the Easy WP SMTP plugin seems like a good alternative.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/